# Count number of Partial order relations of $5$ elements $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

How to count number of Partial order relations of $5$ elements $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? I know that i must use Hasse diagram and count how many distinguishable ways each can enter, but i can't draw them for $5$ elements case. Could you please help to me to do that?

Comment: Is this https://oeis.org/A001035 the sequence you are interested in ? ... "but i can't draw them" Don't you have a pencil & paper ? ...Do $3$ & $4$ first, there are $5$ & $16$ diagrams for these values respectively. If You want to draw them neatly try https://app.diagrams.net/ ... If memory serves, there are $61$ diagrams for $n=5$ and it would take me a while to draw them.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit but do i understand right, that i need to draw them to count number of different relations?

Comment: Yeah to each diagram, there will be a number of different ways to label them. When $n=3$ there are $5$ diagrams & their multiplicities are $1,3,3,6,6$ which adds up to the entry of $19$ in the OEIS A001035 sqeuence.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: There are $63$ diagrams for $n=5$ [OEIS A000112](https://oeis.org/A000112).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that's really bad. and no quick way to count? i mean that's an exercise from book, i don't think that they would ask to draw 63 diagrams

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, I stand corrected, there are $63$ unlabelled posets with $5$ elements. I did draw them once, several years ago ... that was fun $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @french_fries: It’s worse than that, because those $63$ Hasse diagrams give rise to $4231$ distinct partial orders, and I don’t see any easy way to get that total without having the Hasse diagrams: different diagrams give rise to different numbers of partial orders. For instance, there are $5!$ different linear orders, all of which have the same diagram, but there is only $1$ partial order with the diagram `*  *  *  *  *`. I could be missing something, but it does not strike me as a very reasonable exercise.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott my original exercise was to find how many different binary relations that are simultaneously asymmetric and transitive for set of 5 elements. I concluded that we know that a transitive relation is asymmetric if and only if it is irreflexive: if $aRb$ and $bRa$ transitivity gives that $aRa$. It contradicts irreflexivity. As a consequence, a relation is transitive and asymmetric if and only if it is a strict partial order. As the number of strict partial orders is the same as that of partial orders, we need to count number of relations for posets of 5 elements.

Comment: @french_fries: Yes, and unfortunately it seems that no formula (or even recurrence) is known for the number of partial orders on $n$ labelled elements.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but my logic, described above is correct right?

Comment: @french_fries: That a transitive relation is asymmetric iff it is irreflexive, so that the original problem amounts to counting partial orders on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? Yes.